Unity ScriptableObjects being deleted on other machines when pushing to GitHub
A few days ago, I decided to create some structure to my unity project by moving ScriptableObjects (SO) into more detailed folders instead of keeping them all under ScriptableObjects.
After pushing this change, all other machines now delete all SO files after pulling the changes. no matter where in the project they are located.
I've tried reverting said changes, even going as far back as a month ago. But the problem still persists, all SOs are being deleted after creation.

Sounds like bad gitignore

Did you confirm that they have actually been pushed to the remote repo? If not, then your project's .gitignore file is probably filtering them out. Maybe add this file or its contents to your post.

are they actually deleted or did you maybe just forget to include the .meta files as well so just all the references are reset?
